# Given inputs as positive integers $a$,$b$, and $c(i,j)$ where $i,j\leq a$, decide if there is a permutation $\tau$ such that

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

Given inputs as positive integers $a$,$b$, and $c(i,j)$ where $i,j\leq a$, decide if there is a permutation $\tau$ such that 
$$c(\tau(a),\tau(1))+\sum_{i=1}^{a-1} c(\tau(i),\tau(i+1))\leq b
$$
Prove this problem is NP-complete.

The NP-complete problems I have studied are SAT, nSAT, Hamiltonian path and partition sum. The problem looks like an Hamiltonian problem but I am not sure how to connect them. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: $c(i,j)$ can be viewed as a graph ajacency matrix with lengths of edges $c(i,j)$ and you need to find Hamiltonian path with length $\le b$ on it. Or what the $k$ stands for?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin sorry my bad. I've fixed it. What bother me most is the permutation $\tau$. What is the role it plays in here?

Comment: $\tau$ is the order in which paths are visited $\tau(1)$ then $\tau(2)$ etc. You search over permutations $\tau$ of vertices  to find the path.

Comment: @kodlu Yes. Now I am thinking how to reduce Hamiltonian problem to this one. Adding length to each vertices? Find all Hamiltonian paths then count their lengths? Never done this kind of problem before.

Comment: @DDaren, vertices above are $1\dots a$ or $\tau(1),\tau(2),\dots\tau(a)$ and the edges' lengths for are $c(i,j)$ for an edge from vertix $i$ to vertix $j$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I am thinking how to reduce Hamiltonian path to this problem. This problem has length restrained.

Comment: @DDaren: "In the theory of computational complexity, the decision version of the TSP (where, given a length L, the task is to decide whether the graph has any tour shorter than L) belongs to the class of NP-complete problems." [en.wiki/TSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) , so my comments was no help at all

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Thank you! You gave me an important message!